# How can I rewrite this query to be more readable?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following table:

[image]

Find each country that belongs to a continent where all populations are less than 25000000.

```
SELECT name,
       continent,
       population
FROM world
WHERE continent IN
    (SELECT continent
     FROM world t
     WHERE 25000000 > ALL
         (SELECT population
          FROM world
          WHERE continent = t.continent))
```

Can I write this in a better way using a keyword or function that wouldn't require so many levels of nesting?

Comment: Sadikhasan formatted your query and bam, it's more readable. Awesome, don't you think?

Comment: code formatting, the key to everything.

Comment: What you want Query formatting or Query reducing?

Comment: @Sadikhasan Query reducing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for continents where all countries have a population less then 25,000,000. So group by continents and keep those where even the maximum population doesn't exceed this amount.

```
SELECT 
  name,
  continent,
  population
FROM world
WHERE continent IN
(
  SELECT continent
  FROM world
  GROUP BY continent
  HAVING MAX(population) < 25000000
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT w1.name,w1.continent,w1.population
FROM world w1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT continent, SUM(population) as continent_population
    FROM world
    GROUP BY continent        
) w2 ON w2.continent = w1.continent         
WHERE w2.continent_population < 25000000
```

.. or ..

```
SELECT name,continent,population
FROM world w1
WHERE
EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM world w2
    WHERE w2.continent = w1.continent                 
    GROUP BY continent
    HAVING SUM(population) < 25000000            
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Requirement:

> Find each country that belongs to a continent where all populations
>   are less than 25000000.

Most straightforward way I can think of:

```
SELECT name, continent, population FROM world 
WHERE continent in (
SELECT continent FROM world
GROUP BY continent
HAVING SUM(population) < 25000000)
```